# install apk from another android app without using sd card

Tags: android, installation, apk, package-managers

I was able to download an apk file and stored it in my /data/data/com.android.myApp/anotherApp.apk. I was wondering if there is a way I can install this file from another app. I am currently using:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filepath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);

And here is my manifest file:

When I run this. It gives me "Parse Error: There is a problem parsing the package". I dont know what the problem is?
1) Is it I need to store the app in the SD card? I dont want to do that
2) Permission issues?
3) corrupted package being installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you save files on your app sandbox, they are saved under the "files" folder.  So you're full path should be:

```
/data/data/com.android.myApp/files/anotherApp.apk
```

If you are working on an emulator you can do an adb shell ls to confirm if the file is actually there:

```
adb shell "ls /data/data/com.android.myApp/files"
```

Comment: The file is there. I am using Eclipse, I looked it up through DDMS filesystem.

Comment: The file exists. I am concerned that the /data/data directory has read priveldges

Comment: Can you show your code that builds the filepath variable?  In your question, you seem to miss the "/files" element.

Comment: I'm getting same thing here. If I try to install passing file from SD card, it goes OK. But if I try from any other place in "internal memory", I get same error as described. Did you solve this? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Directory entries are only visible via adb if you are running on the Emulator.  On a real device, you can't see anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prepend `filepath` with `file://`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filepath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive"); startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this buddy...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path+"/yourapp.apk")), application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```